Prove $fg$ is integrable if $f$ and $g$ are both integrable.
Note that for all statements of "integrability" below I am referring to Riemann integrability.
Please read: I have already seen the proof where you first prove that $f^2$ is integrable. This I understand. However, I have proven a theorem that says that if $f$ is integrable and $g$ is continuous, $g \circ f$ is integrable. I was told that this could be used to prove that if $f$ and $g$ are integrable, $fg$ is integrable.
However, I'm stuck on how to apply this fact. The fact that neither $f$ nor $g$ is necessarily continuous tells me I will need to create some special function that is continuous in order to utilize the theorem, but I'm out of ideas. Any advice or hints would be appreciated.

@ShyamalSayak Yes, that's what I meant.

The only way I see how to invoke your lemma is to first apply it to the squaring function $s(x)=x^2$, to deduce $f^2=s\circ f$ is integrable, and then polarize to deduce $fg$ is integrable.

Unless you allow yourself to go to higher dimensions as an intermediate step, so you can write $fg=\pi \circ (f,g)$, where $\pi(x,y)=xy$ is the multiplication function.

Thank you. I feel like an idiot for not seeing that.

Altough it doesn't use exactly what you are asking for, if you already know that the sum of integrable functions is integrable and multiplying an integrable function by a scalar also produces an integrable function then you have that $$fg=\frac{1}{2}\left((f+g)^2 -f^2-g^2\right)$$ and using what you stated for the square of a function you are done.
